# Android Studio 3.4 dependencies suggestions - make it to not show alpha/beta versions

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 3.4 added new window `suggestions` in Project Structure which suggest update gradle dependencies to latest version. 
Is it possible to show only final version there without alpha/beta versions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio's Project Structure window provides suggestions to update Gradle dependencies to the latest available versions, including alpha and beta versions. However, Android Studio itself doesn't natively offer an option to filter out alpha or beta versions directly from the Project Structure window.

To achieve the desired behavior of showing only stable (final) versions, you might need to manually review and update the dependencies in your build.gradle files, specifying the exact version number you want to use. For example, instead of using a dynamic version like implementation 'com.example:library:1.+'., you can specify the exact version, such as implementation 'com.example:library:1.2.3'.

Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Open your build.gradle file.
2. Locate the dependency you want to update.
3. Replace the dynamic version with the specific version you want to
   use.

Before:
implementation 'com.example:library:1.+'

After:
implementation 'com.example:library:1.2.3'

By doing this, you have more control over the versions used in your project. However, keep in mind that manually specifying versions means you'll need to stay vigilant about checking for updates to ensure your dependencies are up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

Newer versions of Android Studio only suggest stable versions for dependency updates of this screen (at least since Bumblebee). If someone is still using an old Android Studio version and has this issue, I recommend updating to the newest one.

Comment: As of Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 patch 2 it is suggesting Alpha versions.

Comment: No luck. Even on latest version

Comment: Yes, uncheck this as an answer. It still suggests unstable stuff.